# Is there a way to make a <li> dropdown menu function like a <option> choice menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working with this code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxMRYG

I'd like the user to be able to click one of the "sub items", and then have that submenu replace the "starting item" (much like a standard choice dropdown box would work).

Is this achievable with the code that I have? Is it logical? Before, I was using "option" tags to achieve this, but I couldn't figure out how to have sub-options, so I switched to this format instead.

here is the code in case codepen isn't working:

HTML

```
    <div style="vertical-align:top;">
    <ul class="navbar cf">
            <!-- <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li> -->
            <li style="width:200px;background:222;"><a href="#">starting item</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">sub item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">sub item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">sub item 3</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">google</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">yahoo!</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">jQuery</a>
             <!-- 
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">sub sub item 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">sub sub item 2</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">sub sub sub item 1</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">sub sub sub item 2</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">sub sub sub item 3</a>
                      <ul> 
                        <li><a href="#">sub item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">sub item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">sub item 3</a></li>
                      </ul>
                      </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">sub sub item 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">sub sub item 4</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">sub sub item 5</a>

                  </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li> -->
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">item a little longer</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        <!-- 
            <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 5</a></li> -->
        </ul>
       </div>        



CSS

    /* clearfix */
    /**
     * For modern browsers
     * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
     *    contenteditable attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
     *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
     *    that are clearfixed.
     * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
     *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
     */
    .cf:before,
    .cf:after {
        content: " "; /* 1 */
        display: table; /* 2 */
    }

    .cf:after {
        clear: both;
    }

    /**
     * For IE 6/7 only
     * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
     */
    .cf {
        *zoom: 1;
    }


    ul.navbar {background: #222222; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url();
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222222 0%, #161616 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#222222), color-stop(100%,#161616)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222222 0%,#161616 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #222222 0%,#161616 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #222222 0%,#161616 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #222222 0%,#161616 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#222222', endColorstr='#161616',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
      width: 200px;
      margin: auto; 
      border-radius: 3px;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #555;



    }

    ul.navbar li {
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        position: relative;
    }

    ul.navbar li a {
        display: block;
        /*padding: 13px 44px;*/
        padding:8px 5px;
        color: white !important;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }

    ul.navbar li a:hover,
    ul.navbar li:hover > a {
        background: #39bae6;
        color: #333 !important;
    }

    ul.navbar li ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding:0;
        position: absolute;
        background: #222;
        left: em;
        font-size: 14px;
        min-width: 200px;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        z-index: 99;
        box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.6),
                                0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
        /* transition: all .2s ease-in-out; */
    }

    ul.navbar li ul li { border-top: 1px solid #2a2a2a; }
    ul.navbar li ul li:first-child { border: 0;}
    ul.navbar ul li { float: none; }
    ul.navbar li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; visibility: visible; left: 0; }
    ul.navbar li > ul  ul { top: 0; left: 90%; box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.6);}
    ul.navbar li > ul li:hover ul { left: 100%; }

    ol, ul { list-style: outside none none; }


JS

    // sub menus identification
    $(function() {
      // $('ul.navbar li ul').parent('li').css('background', 'red');
    });


Thank you.
```

edit: I'm having a bit of problems trying to implement the solution. Here is my full page of HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--

-->
<html lang="en">
    <head>


        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styletime.css" />

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/init.js"></script>



    </head>



   <body>

<p>Hello?</p>


<div class="wrap">


    <div style="vertical-align:top;">
    <ul class="navbar cf">
            <!-- <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li> -->
            <li style="width:200px;background:222;"><a href="#">item 3 oh no?</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">sub item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">sub item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">sub item 3</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">google</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">yahoo!</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">jQuery</a>
             <!-- 
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">sub sub item 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">sub sub item 2</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">sub sub sub item 1</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">sub sub sub item 2</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">sub sub sub item 3</a>
                      <ul> 
                        <li><a href="#">sub item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">sub item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">sub item 3</a></li>
                      </ul>
                      </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">sub sub item 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">sub sub item 4</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">sub sub item 5</a>

                  </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li> -->
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">item a little longer</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        <!-- 
            <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 5</a></li> -->
        </ul>
       </div>        


       <div class="adder">
        <div id="container">
            <section id="taskIOSection">
                    <div id="formContainer">
                    <form id="taskEntryForm">
                        <input id="taskInput"  style="font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;" placeholder="Add your interests here..." autocomplete="off"/>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <ul id="taskList"></ul>
            </section>
        </div>
      </div>





 </div> 



    </body>
</html>
```

and here is my full init.js page:

```
/*Adder*/
      $(document).ready(function () {
                            var i = 0;
                            for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
                                var taskID = "task-" + i;
         $('#taskList').append("<li id='" + taskID + "'>" + localStorage.getItem(taskID) + "</li>");
                            }
                            $('#clear').click(function () {
                                localStorage.clear();
                            });
                            $('#taskEntryForm').submit(function () {
                                if ($('#taskInput').val() !== "") {
                                    var taskID = "task-" + i;
                                    var taskMessage = $('#taskInput').val();
                                    localStorage.setItem(taskID, taskMessage);
        $('#taskList').append("<li class='task' id='" + taskID + "'>" + taskMessage + "</li>");
                                    var task = $('#' + taskID);
                                    task.css('display', 'none');
                                    task.slideDown();
                                    $('#taskInput').val("");
                                    i++;
                                }
                                return false;
                            });

                            $('#taskList').on("click", "li", function (event) {
                                self = $(this);
                                taskID = self.attr('id');
                                localStorage.removeItem(taskID);
                                self.slideUp('slow', function () {
                                    self.remove();
                                });

                            });

});




/*MenuClick*/  
$(function() {

$('.navbar > .start-item li > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.navbar > .start-item > a').text($(this).text());
});
}
```

Comment: You can attach a `click` handler to the `sub-items li` and then replace the starting item's content with selected `li`'s content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('.navbar > .start-item li > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.navbar > .start-item > a').text($(this).text());
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/aaqzzd3b/1/

Comment: Thank you very much. This works very well except for when I try to choose a sub-sub menu (i.e. the "jQuery" option under "sub item 3"). Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: You need to prevent default on link click. Check updated answer.

Comment: Me again... Sorry to bug, but I can't get this working on when running the code locally. It could be a problem with my HTML, maybe? I've included my full HTML code in an edit to my original post if you would be able to give advice. I've also included the full init.js with your code added.

Comment: Try to wrap the code into `$(function() { /* code from answer */ })`. Or put the code after your HTML.

Comment: Oi, the problem persists. I've re-updated the init.js status. It also persists if I wrap the code in a "script" tag at the bottom of the body. May I ask if there is a certain JS library I should be importing in the head that I have failed to include?

Comment: Well you need jQuery. Are there any errors in console?

Comment: There are 47 JSLint problems. That's the only place where I can find errors. Here is a screenshot, just in case you wanted to see. http://i.imgur.com/uljLVHp.png I just assumed that the errors didn't matter since I had so many and the website still ran. As for needing jQuery, I do have it in the head of my HTML page, so I guess it isn't that. gah.

Comment: I mean are there errors in console? Open developer tools and check. Other thing make sure you added `.start-item` class to HTML like in my code?

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhh, I did not realize that you had edited the HTML as well. I thought you had only made changes to the JS, so that is all that I copied and pasted over. Wow... I don't feel very bright, haha. Thank you for your help and patience here, everything works like a charm and I am extremely relieved/fascinated/happy. I will look into Developer Tools now in my own interest. Hope you have a very good day.

Comment: Ops, sorry about that, I should have mentioned that I added class for convenience!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

> Updated

```
// sub menus identification
$(function () {
    $(".navbar").on("click", "li", function (event) {
        var liElm = $(event.target).closest("li");
        $(".navbar .caption").text(liElm.find("a:first").text());
        $(".navbar li").removeClass("active");
        liElm.addClass("active");
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/ac5foo03/2/)

Comment: That works perfectly except for with the sub-sub menus! Is there a solution for that? Same problem persisted in other help too, haha.